# Is XPath to find Web Elements with selenium dependent on system where they are executed?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have created a project with eclipse and I have used selenium to access a FireFox driver and find specific url-s by searching in the html.

I have managed to successfully execute the app in my Windows computer, and I get the correct url that I was searching for. But when I export the project and try to execute the project on a Mac, the app doesn't find any web element.

My code is:

```
List<WebElement> urls = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='classname']//li[starts-with(@data-key,'month')]//a"));
```

Is XPath system dependent? How can I modify this code in order to execute it on a Mac computer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure the firefox driver can be found under your Mac?

Comment: yes, because I can manage to open the browser through the app

Comment: That's xpath, not regex.

Comment: XPath is not OS dependent,it works the same. The difference can be in how the page is rendered by the browser on Mac. What errors do you get? Post the complete error message + stacktrace, as well as the HTML of the page .

Comment: The problem is that there aren't any errors, I only get an empty list. I don't have right now the html page, but I'm sure that the xpath is correct. Can you please explain how the rendering process can be different and why it affects the html structure? thank you

Comment: Will using the ChromeDriver() with the chromedriver.exe solve the rendering incompatibility problem??...